# Most efficient way to get MAX value of joined table in LINQ query using C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am trying to find the most efficient way to get the most recent record in a joined table in LINQ.

This query may handle thousands of records so I didn't want to perform a subquery.

I need everything from items, but only the most recent date from the "Notes" table, whose field name is SubmittedDate.

```
var items = (from t1 in db.Items
                         from t2
                            in db.Notes
                           .Where(o => (t1.Item_ID == o.Item_ID))
                         select new ItemModel
                         {
                             Name = t1.Name,
                             MostRecentUpdate = t2.SubmittedDate <== Need max value in model
                         });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you probably just want a group join:

```
var items = from t1 in db.Items
            join t2 in db.Notes on t1.Item_ID equals t2.Item_ID into notes
            select new ItemModel
            {
                Name = t1.Name,
                MostRecentUpdate = notes.Max(x => (DateTime?) x.SubmittedDate)
            };
```

Now `MostRecentUpdate` should be null if there are no non-null dates in the matching `Notes` rows. At least, that's what the LINQ to Objects behaviour would be, so fingers crossed the abstraction holds...

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Will this return null if no items are found in the notes table?

Comment: @Nick: I can make it do so - I hadn't thought of that :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Would you mind? I'm learning! :)

Comment: Don't you need a `let` here? In other words isn't your query re-issuing the `Max` sub query for each item?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Nope, `notes` is a group that's specific to the current `t1`, as it's a group join. There's only one result per `t1`, not one per `t1` / `t2` combination.

Comment: For arguments take, if I had multiple joins fields on notes, could I still do it this way?

Comment: @Nick: You'd probably do `join t2 in db.Notes on new { t1.Id1, t1.Id2 } equals new { t2.Id1, Id2 = t2.OtherId } into notes`

Comment: @JonSkeet: Never mind, hadn't looked at the question closely enough, somehow was under the impression OP needed a *global* max, but then again the join wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Got you - thanks. Are you able to point me in the right direction as to how to allow the equivalent of a left join also (so I can include results where there are no notes stored) ?

Comment: @Nick: This already copes with that, but normally you might want to use a group join then `from note in notes.DefaultIfEmpty()` which will give you a single `null` note value when there are no notes. A search for "linq left join" should help you find more :)